# Mostrar ocultar y volver a mostrar el mismo texto en un lapso de tiempo

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

tengo dos textos. Quiero que primero apareca uno, luego el otro y luego el primer texto... asi en bucle.

Logré que desaparezca el texto uno y aparezca el texto dos. Pero quiero que esto ocurra siempre asi. y logro que se ejecute solo una vez.

mi codigo es:

```
  <div class="content">mi sitio</div>
  <div class="content2" style="display:none;">Bienvenidos!</div>
```

```js
      
   $(document).ready(function() {
setTimeout(function() {
            $(".content").fadeOut(1500);
        },2000);
     
        setTimeout(function() {
            $(".content2").fadeIn(1500);
        },4000);
        
        });
```

```html
<div class="content">Mi sitio</div>
      <div class="content2" style="display:none;">Bienvenidos!</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes usar la funcion [setInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/setInterval) que ejecuta indefinidamente y cada cierto tiempo una funcion, pero para tener el control de cual variable se muestra necesitas una variable en un ambito a tu funcion que llame a `setInterval`.

```js
var showingFirst = true;
$(document).ready(function() {
  setInterval(function() {
    paint()
  }, 6000);
});

function paint() {

  if (showingFirst) {
    setTimeout(function() {
      $(".content").fadeOut(1500);
      showingFirst = !showingFirst;
    }, 2000);

    setTimeout(function() {
      $(".content2").fadeIn(1500);
    }, 4000);
  } else {
    setTimeout(function() {
      $(".content2").fadeOut(1500);
      showingFirst = !showingFirst;
    }, 2000);

    setTimeout(function() {
      $(".content").fadeIn(1500);
    }, 4000);
  }

}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="content">Mi sitio</div>
<div class="content2" style="display:none;">Bienvenidos!</div>
```

Comment: Era eso!!! muchísimas gracias! me salvaste!!!

Comment: en dado caso te sugiero aceptar la respuesta dando click al boton a la izquierda con forma de una paloma